# How to get website content after any sql query/AJAX code in android

Tags: android, ajax, http, request

I would like to get full content of website including some content loaded wich is depend of parameters in GET query. I have website www.example.com?date=2012-12-12. If I use it in any broswer first I see page with "waiting for serwer", after some miliseconds full content is loading. Now I would like to load content of this website after this some miliseconds in android. I don't know how to wait for full loading this.

```
private String makeHTTPRequest() throws IOException
{

    String url = "http://www.centrum.saletyni.pl/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=18&data=2014-11-06";
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    String responseString;
    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        responseString = out.toString();
        //..more logic
    } else{
        //Closes the connection.
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
    return responseString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a thread to execute after this other method is run, or as specified, after a certain amount of time.

e.g. You could use this for a specified time:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx